# Which text has this mantra? Abhratrughneem

Tags: mantras, marriage, shloka, reference-request, hymn

Which scripture text has this hymn? I've heard it used in South Indian marriages.

> abhratrughneem varunApatighneem brihaspatE
>
> indrAputraghneem lakshamamtAmasmai savitassuvah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is from the Baudhayana Grhya Sutra which has apparently not been translated yet.

http://titus.uni-frankfurt.de/texte/etcs/ind/aind/ved/yvs/baudhgs/baudh.htm

> Sentence: 24    puṣpapʰalākṣatamiśrairyavaistilārtʰamupaliṣyāṃ dadʰyodanaṃ samprakīrya dakṣiṇaṃ jānuṃ bʰūmau nidʰāya savyamuddʰr̥tya iḍā devahūḥ iti japitvā nāndīmukʰāḥ pitaraḥ priyantām iti vācayitvā adya vivāhaḥ iti brāhmaṇānannena pariviṣya puṇyāhaṃ svasti r̥ddʰim ityoṅkārapūrvaṃ tristrirekaikāmāśiṣo vācayitvā snāto 'hatavāso gangʰānuliptassragvī bʰuktavān pratodapāṇirapadātirgatvā vadʰūjñātibʰiratitʰivadarcitassnātāmahatavāsasāṃ gandʰānuliptāṃ sragviṇīṃ bʰuktavatīmiṣuhastāṃ dattāṃ vadʰūṃ samīkṣate **abʰrātr̥gʰnīṃ varuṇāpatigʰnīṃ br̥haspate \ indrāputragʰnīṃ lakṣmyaṃ tāmasyai savitassuva iti** \24\

A translaion of the wedding mantras that includes this verse goes:

> That fortune which is not brother-killing O Varuna, which is not husband killing O Brhaspati, which is not son-killing O Indra, direct that to this woman.

The verse seems to a slightly modified form of 14 1 62 of the Saunakiya Atharva Veda Samhita

> abhrātṛghnīṃ varuṇāpaśughnīṃ bṛhaspate
> indrāpatighnīm putriṇīmasmabhyaṃ savitarvaha

> अभ्रातृघ्नीं वरुणापशुघ्नीं बृहस्पते ।
> इन्द्रापतिघ्नीं पुत्रिणीमास्मभ्यं सवितर्वह ॥६२

> O Varuna, O Brhaspati, O Indra, O Savita, pray lead and bring the bride to our home. O bridegroom, young man of noble qualities as Varuna, educated and enlightened with wide knowledge like Brhaspati, strong and powerful as Indra, and virile and brave as Savita, conduct home this bride who is noble and helpful to brothers and sisters, loving to the husband and kind to the animals of the home. Escort her for us, bring her home. And may God bless her as mother of noble children.

Devanagari with Hindi commentary at

https://vedicheritage.gov.in/flipbook/Atharvaveda_Subodh_Bhashya_Vol_IV/#book/314